# How to create Image from string in Base64 (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

I am making a Note application where I can draw with Windows ink and also paste images. I want to save the images and ink in a single file. Therefore I am converting the image to a string in base64 format so that I can easily serialize it. My problem is when I try to recreate the image from the string.

My code to decode the image data into a base64 string:

```
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
var bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();

base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

My code to encode the base64 string into an image again (**This code does NOT work! The image is not added to the redCanvas**):

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
    stream.Seek(0);
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
}
Image image = new Image();

image.Source = bitmapImage;

// Add the image to a second canvas
redCanvas.Children.Add(image);
```

Full code for pasting the image and creating the base64 string:

```
private async Task myButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataPackageView = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();
    if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
    {
        IRandomAccessStreamReference imageReceived = null;
        imageReceived = await dataPackageView.GetBitmapAsync();
        if (imageReceived != null)
        {
            using (var imageStream = await imageReceived.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);

                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
                var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
                var bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();

                base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

                TextBox_Image_Base64.Text = base64;
         
                Image image = new Image();
                        
                // Add the image to a list of Images
                ListImages.Add(image);

                blueCanvas.Children.Add(image);

                image.Source = bitmapImage;

                TextBlock_Status.Text = "Status : Image is retrieved from the 
                                                 clipboard and pasted successfully.";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TextBlock_Status.Text = "Status : Bitmap format is not available in clipboard";
    }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can recreate the image from the string?

[Screenshot from my app showing that I am able to paste an image and decode it into a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J5yu.png)

Comment: @Peter Smith. I am declaring base64String in the class scope. Also, what should I use your line of code for?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Okay, just thinking aloud about the encoding/decoding methods. I'll delete the comments.

Comment: @Peter [A trivial example](https://rextester.com/ZDS72009)

Comment: OP: what is the issue you're facing with the code you've shown? "This code does not work" isn't really clear. Do you get an error of some kind? What?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar The image that should be created from the string is never added to the redCanvas, and when I check the bitmapImage properties: PixelHeight and PixelWidth I get 0 for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create Image from string in Base64 (UWP)

We suggest you convet stream buffer to Base64 from imageStream diteactly, but not from PixelData. you could use [`CryptographicBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/encode-and-decode-data) class to approach.

```
using (var imageStream = await imageReceived.OpenReadAsync())
{
    var buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)imageStream.Size);

    await imageStream.ReadAsync(buffer, (uint)imageStream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

    String strBase64New = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer);

   
}
```

Retrive from base64 string

```
public static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadBase64(string base64)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(ms.AsRandomAccessStream());
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```